# Python - How to find the longest sequence in a integer list of neighbor numbers

Tags: python

How I find the longest sub-list in list of number pairs that has the difference of 1.
So "number neighbors" could be element 1 and 2 or element 7 and 6.

If the list is [7, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0],
Then the desired output should be 4. The sub-list would be then [7, 6, 5, 6].

This is what I have for now. The for loop formula is really broken and I don't know how to solve this.

```
list = [7, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0]

sublist = []
for i in list:
    if list[i] - list[i+1] == 1 or list[i] - list[i+1] == -1:
        sublist.append(i)
                
print(sublist)
print(len(sublist))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its best to break these types of problems up into their parts

the **main problem** here is to get **all** sequential sequences

```
def get_sequences_iter(an_array):     
    # start a new sequence with first value (or empty)
    sequence = an_array[:1] 
    # check each index with the value that comes before 
    for idx in range(1,len(an_array)):
        if an_array[idx] - an_array[idx-1] in {1,-1}:
            # this is part of a run append it
            sequence.append(an_array[idx])
        else:
            # run is broken
            yield sequence
            # start a new run
            sequence = [an_array[idx]]
     #capture final sequence
     yield sequence
```

once you have this you can get all the runs in a list in O(n) time

```
sequences =  get_sequences_iter([7, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0])
for sequence in sequences:
    print(sequence)
```

hopefully with this information you can figure out how to solve your actual question

but just in case

```
print(max(sequences,key=len))
```

Answer (score 4):

[more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_when) makes it simple:

```
from more_itertools import split_when

lst = [7, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0]

print(max(split_when(lst, lambda x, y: abs(x - y) != 1), key=len))
```